# Curl - Unreadable data

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl in PHP to fetch an image from another website and the output is unreadable. It's like `+�<�@�9�3�*zB�<�4�<�I�;�4�2�;�3xO�`. I'm using php7 on XAMPP.

```
$ch = curl_init();

$option = array(
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $user_agent,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $option);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$responseInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
$headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: check the `Content-Encoding:` header, its probably gzip

Comment: On my it says `image/gif`

Comment: ah my bad did not read that well, you cant hsr echo an image strme unless you se the headers locally. you could save it to a file can call in a web page. but echo\print_r will show you the binary unless you told the broeser to expect an image

Comment: I found my problem, i forgot to define all the header. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```